# Regex to extract only domain from sub-domains

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i will be using the expression with

```
Regex.Replace();
```

to replace the rest with "".

inputs:
http://therealzenstar.blogspot.fr
output:
blogspot.fr

Comment: Your question is really, really vague. Edit it to add some more detail - what are the inputs? What is the expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be aware that the quality of your question stronlgy relates to how good people can help you. There is too little information in your question (yet) to generate any meaningful answers. Please edt it with some more details. Have a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `/https?:\/\/\w+\.(\w+\.\w+)/`  this can work for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to iterate on Jens' comment, we have to guess: What is your expected output when additional information appears, e.g. `http://therealzenstar.blogspot.fr/somedata.html`. Is it still `blogspot.fr`? Are such examples needed to be adresed?

You said you want to replace "everything else" with `""`. `Replace()` will replace everything that is matched with what you want. So, to replace it with `""`, you'd need to match everything that you **do not want**.It's possible, however, it's much easier to capture what you DO want and replace all the match with $1.

Assuming you always want only the `domain.xx`, even if more information appears. Something like this will work: `^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/\s]*\.([^.\s\/]*\.[^.\s\/]*)(?:$|\/.*)`, as seen: https://regex101.com/r/hN8iQ7/1

A problem arises if your domains also include those with multiple extensions. I.e. `domain.co.uk`. You'd need to adress them specifically (naming them), as it is very hard to generalize a way to distinguish these items.

`^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/\s]*?\.([^.\s\/]*\.(?:co\.uk|[^.\s\/]*))(?:$|\/.*)` - with `.co.uk` option added. https://regex101.com/r/hN8iQ7/2 .

`yourregex.Replace(yourstring, "$1")` may do what you need.